# How to run the following aggregation query using spring-data-mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to reshape the document using projection in mongo. How can I run the following query in spring-data-mongo?

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  { $project : { date: { $toDate : {$multiply:['$timestamp',1000]} }, status:1} },
  { $group : { _id : { hour : { $hour: '$date' }} ,
        count : { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

Result should have count of documents grouped by hour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you could do using `mongoTemplate`. I haven't tested it though.

```
Document multiplyTime = new Document("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$timestamp", 1000));
ProjectionOperation project1 = project("status").and(ConvertOperators.ToDate.toDate(multiplyTime)).as("date");
ProjectionOperation project2 = project().and(DateOperators.Hour.hour("date")).as("hour");
GroupOperation group = group("hour").count().as("count");
mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(project1, project2, group),"yourCOllection", Document.class);
```